# Backbone - am I accessing this Model correctly?

Tags: backbone.js

I have this function in my view:

```
saveData: function(){
    this.collection.setSelected(this.collection.where({name : this.$('#projects').val()}));
}
```

And the corresponding function in my collection:

```
setSelected: function(project){
    this.each(function(model){
        model.set({selected: false});
    });
    project[0].set({selected: true});
}
```

So, my question is why am I required to access the first element of the Project array to access the actual Model? Am I doing something wrong?

Also, it seems a little OTT to loop round all the models in the collection setting to false to then set one to true, is this the correct way to do things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why am I required to access the first element of the Project array to access the actual Model

Because you're using [`where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where), which returns an array.  You could use [`find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) in this case, which returns the first matching object.

```
this.collection.find(function(x) { return x.get("name") == this.$('#projects').val() });
```

> it seems a little OTT to loop round all the models in the collection

If you only want one model selected at a time, then it might be better to find the selected one and deselect it.  Something like:

```
this.collection.setSelected(this.$('#projects').val());
```

And:

```
setSelected: function(name){
    var selected = this.find( function(x) { return this.get("selected") === true } );
    if (typeof selected != "undefined") selected.set("selected", false);

    var newSelected = this.find( function(x) { return this.get("name") === name });
    if (typeof newSelected != "undefined") newSelected.set("selected", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me get this straight, this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
USER SELECTS VIEW ELEMENT
GET NAME FROM ELEMENT
VIEW SETS ALL MODELS SELECTED = FALSE
VIEW SETS MODEL MATCHING NAME SELECTED = TRUE
```

Well first of all I would say you don't need to loop all the models as it looks like there will only ever be one model with `selected=true`. If that is the case you can simply use some other [underscore collection methods](http://underscorejs.org/#collections) available, and I would also only pass the name value to `setSelected` to get keep things simple in the view:

```
saveData: function(){
    this.collection.setSelected(this.$('#projects').val());
}

setSelected: function(name) {
    this.findfindfunction(model) {
        return model.get('selected');
    }).set('selected', false);

    this.find(function(model) {
        return model.get('name') == name;
    }).set('selected', true);
}
```

Obviously using the `find` method still requires some looping under the hood to find the model that matches the conditions, but it only searches for the first one that passes the condition, so it's better than doing a `where` which loops ever model regardless.

Obviously this all falls apart if there is can be more than one model selected :D

**UPDATE**

Upon thinking about your problem a bit more I think that you might be better served with a different view architecture. In the situation you describe, I personally usually use micro-views. i.e. a small view per model. The view markup may simply consist of a checkbox, nothing else.

This means in your main view, you can loop your collection, and for each model create a view, pass the model to the view, render it, and append the markup to the main view.

This way you have more control over events which relate specifically individual models, and it makes it easy rendering model specific values to your view. This simple view below is simple example of a micro-view where the template would consist of just a checkbox and a label, or something simillar.

```
var CheckboxView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'input[type=checkbox]': 'select'
    },
    render: function () {
        var html = _.template($('#myTemplate'), this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);

        return this;
    },
    select: function () {
        this.model.set('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why am I required to access the first element of the Project array to access the actual Model?**

Answer is, according to [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where), `where` returns an array of matched models. Hence you need to access it using an index.

I don't see anything wrong with the approach you have used to set `selected` to `true` as long as `where` returns only one model.

**Second Doubt**

Why don't you create the all the models with `selected` as `false` (I'm assuming it would be fine) and keep `setSelected` method like this:

```
setSelected = function(project, value) {

  project[0].set({selected: value});

  // well a better approach would be to define a method in the model saying,
  // select() which sets the attribute, and call it from here with
  // project[0].select(params), but its up to you how you do it.
}
```

You can call the same method with `true` or `false` to `select` or `deselect` any model.